# How i can resize Adobe Illustrator Artwork (AI) File to increased Dimension without losing quality in PHP using ImageMagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick

When user upload AI file then if Dimension of an uploaded file is less than or equal to (180 x 180) then I want to resize this file to increased dimension (277 x 277) and then convert it to JPG. I tried code mentioned below. I tried all ways which are commented in the code.

```
    $image_rs = new Imagick();
    $image_rs->readimage(realpath(SOURCE_UPLOAD_PATH.$source_file_name));
    if($fileType == "ai"){
        $image_rs->setIteratorIndex(0);
    }
    $dimensions = $image_rs->getImageGeometry();
    $width = $dimensions['width'];
    $height = $dimensions['height'];
    if($width <= 180 && $height <= 180){
        //$image_rs->magnifyImage();
        $image_rs->setImageFormat($source_file_ext);
        $image_rs->scaleImage(277,0); 
        // $image_rs->adaptiveResizeImage(277,277);
        // $image_rs->resizeImage(277,277,\Imagick::FILTER_CATROM, 1, true); 
        $image_rs->writeImage(realpath(RESIZED_UPLOAD_PATH)."/". $source_file_name);

        $image = new Imagick();
        $image->readimage(realpath(RESIZED_UPLOAD_PATH.$source_file_name));
        if($fileType == "ai"){
            $image->setIteratorIndex(0);
        }
        $dimensions = $image->getImageGeometry();
        $width = $dimensions['width'];
        $height = $dimensions['height'];
        $image->thumbnailImage($width, $height);
        $image->writeImage(realpath(CONVERTED_UPLOAD_PATH)."/". $source_file_name_without_ext.".jpg");
    }
```

**Issue:** By using this code image is resized successfully but resized AI file also becomes blurry. because of Imagick library when resizing the image it converts AI file to jpg. AI file is vector file so there is no chance to become blurry even if we increase dimension. So how I can do this by imagemagick?

Comment: Try setting the destination size _before_ reading the vector graphic with `$image_rs->setSize(277, 277)`.

Comment: changing destination size before reading file is not working for vector graphic,its only working for images.if any another library for same is available in PHP, please inform me.